# Unable to verify signature from Sendgrid event webhook

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid

I am struggling to get the signed event webhooks working:

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook-security-features

I have enabled them and can see the headers but verifySignature() always returns false.

This is what I have:

```
$eventWebhook = new EventWebhook();
$ecPublicKey = $eventWebhook->convertPublicKeyToECDSA($publicKey));
$payload = json_encode( $request->all()[0] ) . "\r\n";

$valid = $eventWebhook->verifySignature(
            $ecPublicKey,
            $payload,
            $request->header('X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature'),
            $request->header('X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp')
        );
```

I am getting multiple events so added the [0]

Answer (score 3):

Got it working like this:

```
$eventWebhook = new EventWebhook();
$ecPublicKey = $eventWebhook->convertPublicKeyToECDSA(Cache::get('sendgrid-key'));
$payload =  $request->getContent();
return $eventWebhook->verifySignature(
            $ecPublicKey,
            $payload,
            $request->header('X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature'),
            $request->header('X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp')
        );
```